# Select only parents with one child

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
  FROM Users
  JOIN Streams ON Users.Id = Streams.UserId
  JOIN Playlists ON Streams.Id = Playlists.StreamId
  WHERE Playlists.FirstItemId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
  //  Doesn't work
  HAVING COUNT(1) = (
    SELECT COUNT(Playlists.Id)
    FROM Playlists WHERE Playlists.StreamId = Streams.Id
)
```

I'm trying to select all Users who have only Streams with 1 Playlist and whose 1 Playlist has a FirstItemId of Guid.Empty. I'm trying to do some database maintenance and remove accounts which were created but never used.

I've got the first part of the query working pretty well, but I'm not sure how I can apply my 'Having only 1 child' filter properly.

Comment: Can you describe the Users, Streams, and Playlists tables?

Comment: Users have a 1 to many relationship with Streams. Streams have a 1 to many relationship to Playlists. I'll add a screenshot of the tables if that'd help?

Comment: Is your problem simply the count keyword? That is, in your having clause, can you just compare the subquery to "1" instead of "COUNT(1)"?

Comment: It says that I can't apply having because I haven't used a GroupBy or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the query below, to select inactive user out

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
FROM Users
JOIN Streams ON Users.Id = Streams.UserId
JOIN Playlists ON Streams.Id = Playlists.StreamId
WHERE Playlists.FirstItemId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
AND (SELECT COUNT(Playlists.Id) FROM Playlists WHERE Playlists.StreamId = Streams.Id) =1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can accomplish this pretty easily with a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
  FROM Users
  JOIN Streams ON Users.Id = Streams.UserId
  JOIN Playlists ON Streams.Id = Playlists.StreamId
  WHERE Playlists.FirstItemId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Playlists
    WHERE Playlists.StreamId <> Playlists.FirstItemId
  )
)
```

Comment: This is close. I think it gives me an idea on how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: @seanmk +1 made my answer easier to write

Answer (score 1):

@seanmk has a good idea ... like this ...

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
  FROM Users
  JOIN Streams ON Users.Id = Streams.UserId
  JOIN Playlists p ON Streams.Id = p.StreamId
  WHERE p.FirstItemId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Playlists q
    WHERE q.Id = p.Id
      AND q.FirstItemId <> p.FirstItemId
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query below should meet your requirements.

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
FROM Users
JOIN Streams ON Users.Id = Streams.UserId
JOIN Playlists ON Streams.Id = Playlists.StreamId
WHERE Playlists.FirstItemId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
AND Playlists.StreamId IN (
  SELECT Playlists.StreamId
  FROM Playlists
  GROUP BY Playlists.StreamId
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sub-querys, having, or group by:

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Streams ON Users.Id = Streams.UserId
INNER JOIN Playlists p1 ON Streams.Id = p1.StreamId AND p1.FirstItemId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
LEFT JOIN Playlists p2 ON Streams.ID = p2.StreamID and p2.FirstItemID <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
WHERE p2.StreamID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way of looking at the question.  Instead of using `exists`, it uses aggregation for the conditions:

```
select top 4000 Id
from (SELECT u.Id,
             min(FirstItemId) as MinFI,
             max(FirstItemId) as MaxFI,
             min(p.Id) as minpid,
             max(pid) as maxpid
      FROM Users u JOIN
           Streams s
           ON u.Id = s.UserId join
           Playlists p
           ON s.Id = p.StreamId
      group by u.id
     ) u
where MinFi = MaxFi and MinFi = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' and
      minpid = maxpid;
```

I'm not sure which versions would perform better.  This is just an alternative way of looking at your problem.